# NA Values Appear for All Data in Imported .csv File

Tags: r, na

I imported a set of data into RStudio containing 85 variables and 139 observations.  All values are integers except for the last column which is blank and for some reason was imported alongside everything else in the .csv file I created from a .xls file.

As such, this last column is all `NA` values.  The problem is that when I try to run any kind of analysis it seems to be reading that *all* values are `NA` values.  Despite this, in the data window in RStudio everything seems to be fine.  Are there solutions to this problem that don't involve the data?  Is it almost certainly the data that's the problem?

It seems strange that when opening the file anywhere else and even viewing it in R

Comment: Try `sapply(strsplit(readLines("your.csv"), ","), length)` and if they're not all equal you have a stray comma in the unequal line.

Comment: When running your analysis, are you excluding your NA column? Dropping the column out of your dataframe prior to any analysis may help you out.

Comment: @Richard I just tested that and they did come out all equal.  That's a handy trick to know though, thanks.

Comment: @Bernardo I tried running it with and without the problem column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely issue is that the file is being imported as all text rather than as numeric data. If all of the data is numeric you can just use `colClasses="numeric"` as an argument to the `read.csv()` function and that should import correctly. You could also change the data class once it is in R, or give `colClasses` a vector of different classes if you have a variety of different data types (logical, character, numeric etc.) in your file.

**Edit**
Seeing as `colClasses` is not working (it is hard to say why without looking at your data), you can try this:

```
MyDF<-data.frame(sapply(MyDF,FUN=as.numeric))
```

Where MyDF is your datafraome. That will change all of your columns to numeric. If you have some charcter/factor/logical values in there this may not work as expected. You might want to check your excel file/csv to see why it is importing a NA column. It could be that there is a cell with a space in it that is being pulled in and this is throwing things off. You could always try deleting that empty column and retrying your import.

Comment: No luck unfortunately.  I tried `A <- read.csv("Test.File",colClasses="numeric"), but the same issue arose.

Comment: If you use the `class()` command on one of the columns of the data.frame does it verify that it is numeric?

Comment: Thanks, all the ones I've tested so far come back as "character" - that will be a very helpful test in the future.  Any ideas as to why the colClasses="numeric" solution may not be working though?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to omit your last column while reading the data itself, you can try the following code. In this example, I am assuming that your file has 5 columns and the 5th column has NA values. So, you want to skip reading 5th column in your data set.

```
data <- read.csv (fileName, ....) [,1:4]
```

or, if you want to use column names, you can use:

```
data <- read.csv (fileName, ....) [,c('col1','col2','col3','col4')]
```

This will read all the observations from selected columns within your data set.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, this still reads all the columns.  The subset occurs after reading.

Comment: Yes, but since its omitted from the 'data' object, the column would be missing for any further data analysis.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying too find the mean and standard deviation you can use

```
Data<- mean( dataframe$colname , na.rm = TRUE) 
Data1<- sd( dataframe$colname , na.rm = TRUE)
```

This will give u the answer after omitting the na values from the column